# Using enter key to check CheckBoxes in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, key, enter

I want to use Enter key instead of Space key to check the checkboxes..

```
private void Form2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox c1 = this.ActiveControl as CheckBox;
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter && this.ActiveControl.Equals(c1))
                c1.Checked = true;
        }
```

I could do it if i write this code in the KyeUp of the checkbox, but the thing is, I have several Checkboxes in the form and I cant write this under each of their KeyUp, so I need to use it under the KeyUp of the form.. 
What do I need to change??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the form's [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property to true.

Alternatively, you could loop through the checkboxes (using the `Controls` property, perhaps recursively) and add the same handler to every checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Simply determine which control has the focus and check/uncheck it as appropriate.  This link should help: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-36261.html